# What is funny about monoids?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, monoid

I was looking for an introduction to Semigroups and found an [Introduction to Semigroups and Monoids](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/semigroup.pdf) by Pete L. Clark. The abstract says:

> I know many working mathematicians who let loose a smirk or giggle when they hear the word “monoid”. What’s so funny?

I learnt many useful things reading the paper but didn't see this question resolved. Perhaps the author intended to answer it in a later section (the paper is incomplete).

So, why might a working mathematician smirk when they hear the word "monoid"?

Comment: When they put it like that, the word does sound kinda funny. But whether there is an actual joke hidden there, I don't know.

Comment: I have noticed across several books that mathematicians, despite knowing that they are not really all that funny, cannot resist the urge to make jokes. This, I imagine, is one of those jokes.

Comment: Perhaps they think they're useless, due to the prevalence of/focus on groups in the curriculum.

Comment: What is not funny at all is the very poor quality of this introduction, which certainly will not help semigroup theory to be better known to mathematicians. I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Although the tone of the excerpt is a bit unusual for mathematical exposition, the question is a sincere one.  To place it in a bit more context: the term "monoid" is not at the same level of ubiquity in the vocabularies of American mathematicians as other algebraic structures like "group", "ring" or "field", and in most undergraduate courses in the US one does even encounter the term.  This presumably is why many people smirk or gigle.

Comment: To respond to @J.-E. Pin's comment: yes, **I agree**, and for that reason I removed these notes from my page of expositions.   Perhaps I should remove the file from my departmental server entirely; that would however break some links, as with this question...

Comment: There's nothing funny about monoids.  Monoids are used extensively in formal language theory, and there's nothing funny about having to debug code that parses one of these languages.